# descargar e instalar imagen de Docker offline

Tags: docker

Actualmente estoy trabajando con poco acceso a internet y comencé a trabajar con Docker. Vi que para instalar una imagen puedo ejecutar el comando `docker pull <image_name>`. Mi pregunta es si puedo descargar varias imagenes de Docker (en un comprimido por ejemplo) y después instalarlas en una computadora sin conexión. Cómo se puede hacer esto y de donde puedo descargar dichas imágenes?

Comment: No se si podrás encontrar un comprimido de imágenes docker, pero una vez hecho el pull deberían estar en alguna de las subcarpetas de /var/lib/docker de tu equipo. Echa un vistazo a https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/5248611 para más info

Comment: debes crear un docker server y alli descargar tus imagenes; mira [esta imagen](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry) puedes tener tu server hub

Answer (score 2):

Es difícil encontrar imágenes docker para descargar "como archivo", ya que el resultado final viene a ser el mismo que hacer un `docker pull <image_name>` (y este último es más cómodo).

Si lo que quieres es guardarlas en archivo para pasarlas a otra máquina sin conexión (o por la razón que sea), puedes hacer `docker pull <image_name>` para bajar la imagen que quieras, exportar la imagen a un archivo `tarball` con [save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/)...

```
docker save -o archivo.tar <image_name>
```

...e importarla con [load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/):

```
docker load -i archivo.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontré esta herramienta que me permite descargar las imagenes comprimidas desde un "mirror". Especialmente hecha para aquellos paises donde el docker hub esta bloqueado. La recomiendo https://github.com/jadolg/DockerImageSave/